# how to copy a full sheet from one workbook to another workbook with shift in the tope corner cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am trying to copy a full sheet from one open workbook to another open workbook  with a shift in the top corner cell, something like

```
workbook(f1).sheets(s1).cells.copy _
    workbook(f2).sheets(s2).range(cells(3,3))
```

Here the top left corner in the destination sheet s2 is cell(3,3)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general case this code should work:

```
Workbooks(f1).Sheets(s1).UsedRange.Copy Workbooks(f2).Sheets(s2).Cells(3,3)
```

But if the size of a used range is too big to be shifted inside of a limited space of a worksheet, then you'll get an error. For example, if you have data in all rows up to the last one then you'll not be able to shift them down. Another factor to keep in mind is that the used range not always starts from `A1`. Some columns or rows at the beginning may be empty. If this empty space is meaningful, we can try this workaround:

```
Set Source Workbooks(f1).Sheets(s1)
Set Destination Workbooks(f2).Sheets(s2)
Source.Range( _
   .Cells(1,1), _
   .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCelltypeLastCell) _
).Copy Destination.Cell(3,3)
```